# Look and Feel no java

Tags: java, swing

Tenho uma aplicação que uso Windows Look and Feel. Porém tenho um problema em que o usuário pode ter um computador com Windows XP, e tudo fica estilizado com windows XP.

Tem como a aplicação ficar com o look and feel de compilação (ou algo do genero), pois uso Windows 10 e gostaria que aplicação tivesse essa aparência no cliente também. Aqui na empresa utilizamos o Nimbus, porém esse look and feel já está muito defasado, e gostaria de tentar dar uma cara nova ao sistema.

Answer (score 7):

Nativamente não, pois provavelmente você está utilizando o *lookandfeel(LAF)* que adapta a aparência da aplicação conforme o gerenciador de janelas do sistema em execução, e neste caso, ele vai se adaptar conforme o SO em que estiver rodando.

Além do Nimbus, há o LAF `javax.swing.plaf.metal` nativamente, ambos são *cross-plataform*, mas talvez a aparência dele também não seja tão interessante. Além deles, se quiser manter a aparência independente do sistema em execução, você precisará [criar seu próprio LAF](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html) ou utilizar algum personalizado por alguém. Geralmente essas soluções personalizadas são achadas somente pagas, ou gratuitas pra testar e com marca d'água.

Swing infelizmente já está, por si, muito defasado e esquecido, até por ser uma tecnologia desktop muito antiga, então é difícil achar uma solução mais simples e que não onere custos de comprar um tema. Se realmente precisa de uma aplicação desktop em java e quer personalizar, sugiro que dê uma lida na API [javafx](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/javafx-docs-2159875.html), além de ser mais atual, ela é mais flexível quanto a personalização, possuindo até recursos semelhantes ao da web, como folhas de estilos.

---

**Referencia:**

- [Lesson: Modifying the Look and Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html)

Comment: O problema é que tenho uma aplicação inteira feita em Swing, ter que refazer ela em JavaFX levaria mais um bom tempo...Mas enfim, só queria algum LnF que fosse ficasse igual em todos SOs sem ser muito feio. Pois o problema, segundo meu chefe, é que em versões diferentes do SO o LnF do windows não funciona muito bem

Comment: @William então só te restam as duas opções que mencionei: procurar algum LAF de terceiros e compra-lo ou estudar como criar um e fazer o seu proprio.

Comment: Acho que o último grande investimento em LAF que houve foi o nimbus no final da era da Sun, junto com o JavaFX. Depois disso, muito pouco foi investido nessa área, pois a Oracle têm pouco interesse nisso e o pouco que tinha foi quase todo para o JavaFX.

Comment: Infelizmente o nimbus foi a única coisa que me restou, deixando o sistema com aquela cara de windows XP diferente